# canvas, drawImage does not work for remote picture

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I want to draw a picture from web, so I have the following html5 code, that's the example from  W3C Shool, but when I load the html page in Chrome, the image was displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
            var img=new Image();
            img.src='http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/ct_html5_canvas_image.gif';
            cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The image is from w3school, I can view it in my Chrome, my Chrome is the latest version, so I don't know where the problem is, I even try to download the picture to my local machine and place it in the same directory of the html page above, change the code to img.src='flower.gif', but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to draw the image before it has been loaded. Try something like this:

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var cxt = c.getContext("2d");

        var img=new Image();
        img.src='http://www.w3school.com.cn/i/ct_html5_canvas_image.gif';

        img.onload = draw;

        function draw(){               
            cxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);            
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: Why W3C didn't mention this on their web page? they give an example without the onload function. http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=html5_canvas_image